# angularjs ui-router don't work

Tags: angularjs

I try to use the ui-router plugin for angular, but it doesn't work..

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="tester">
<div ui-view> </div>
</body>
<!-- BEGIN CORE ANGULARJS PLUGINS -->
<script src="../assets/global/plugins/angularjs/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../assets/global/plugins/angularjs/plugins/angular-ui-router.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- END CORE ANGULARJS PLUGINS -->
<script src="app2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
var tester= angular.module("GhibliUploader", [
"ui.router"]);
tester.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',         function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    // Redirect any unmatched url
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/dashboard");

    $stateProvider

    // Dashboard
      .state('dashboard', {
         // url: "./view/dashboard.html",
          template:"cciocicoicocicocicoioicoico"
    });
}]);

tester.run();
```

I get always a blank page! But I see the URL using the route correctly.

Why doesn't it work? If I try to use this tutorial [ui-router debug](http://tech.endeepak.com/blog/2014/05/03/debugging-angular-ui-router/) I have only the injector being undefined.

Comment: template:'view/dashboard.html'

Comment: Alaksandar Jesus Gene, template he must print only taht string. if work i try use page html

Comment: for all, var tester= angular.module("GhibliUploader" it'a a error.
 var tester= angular.module("tester" , but this not resolve my problem

Comment: if i use not min ui-route.js file i catch this console error

updateView (http://angular.localhost/assets/global/plugins/angularjs/plugins/angular-ui-router.js:4023:23) <!-- uiView: undefined -->

Comment: change in index.html "<ui-view></ui-view>" the error is vanish

Comment: now work. only insert property .state('dashboard', {
         **url: "/dashboard",**
          template:"cciocicoicocicocicoioicoico"
    });

Answer (score 0):

In index.html you use `<body ng-app="tester">`

But you are defining your angular app as `GhibliUploader`

Try `angular.module("tester", ["ui.router"]);`

Comment: it's only my errot  in copy , paste and replace. it's all "tester", if you try you always the same problem

Comment: `url: "./view/dashboard.html"` needs to be `url: "/dashboard"`